# Variable used to declare size of heap for object being set to null once object is set to null?

Tags: c++

I have a variable that is an array on the heap. I declared this array on the heap using and an integer value that i set times the sizeOf the object. I am having trouble in my code that when I set my object to null, the integer used to create space for it is set to 0.

```
int numOfNodes;
int numOfEdges;

FILE *file;
file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfNodes); //numOfNodes value is read in correct here             
fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfEdges);//numOfEdges value is read in correct here

ELEMENT **T = (ELEMENT**) new ELEMENT()//setting space on the heap for an array of linked lists 


for(int i=0; i<numOfNodes; i++){//This line is supposed to initialize all the Linked List inside the array to NULL. However on the second iteration the value for int numOfNodes changes to 0.
T[i]=NULL}
```

Not sure whats going on in that the array of Linked Lists and the int numOfNodes have nothing to do with each other beyond that the numOfNodes is used as a number to allocate an appropriate amount of space on the heap.

EDIT:Used new instead of malloc but still running into the same problem

Comment: Since this is c++ don’t use malloc, use new. And you have a double pointer but you’re not allocating space for pointers, you’re allocating for the structs themselves. This would not work if you used `new` and you would get a proper error message.

Comment: ELEMENT *   as the result of the malloc would be sufficient. It is an array of struct ELEMENT so a  simple pointer would be sufficient

Comment: With your simple pointer you have to initialize all fields of the ELEMENT structure one by one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: It would be much simpler to just use a `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int numOfNodes= 0; // good practice: always initialize
int numOfEdges= 0; // ditto

FILE* file= fopen("input.txt", "r"); // ditto
// you should check fscanf return value
fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfNodes); //numOfNodes value is read in correct here             
fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfEdges); //numOfEdges value is read in correct here
```

You should also check that those numbers are > 0.

This is bad, don't do this following:

```
ELEMENT **T = (ELEMENT**) new ELEMENT()
```

You're asking memory for *just one element*,
and the memory you're getting is `ELEMENT*`.
By *forcing* the cast to `ELEMENT**`, you are not only
doing something wrong, but telling the compiler 'trust me, I know what I'm doing'. 
As a general rule in C++,
if you're casting, you're doing something bad.
There usually is a better way.
And don't use old style cast, prefer 
`reinterpret_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast` and `const_cast`.

If what you want is an array of `ELEMENT*`, 
then you should ask for it:

```
typedef ELEMENT* pElement;
ELEMENT** T= new pElement[numOfNodes]; // delete with delete[] T;
// or:
ELEMENT** T= malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT*) * numOfNodes); // delete with free(T);
```

Now you can do:

```
for (int i= 0; i < numOfNodes; i++) {
  // This line is supposed to initialize all the Linked List inside the array to NULL.
  // However on the second iteration the value for int numOfNodes changes to 0.
  T[i]= NULL; // nullptr on C++11
}
```

In modern c++ I think the for is not needed if you do:

```
ELEMENT** T= new pElement[numOfNodes]{}; // delete with delete[] T;
```

Also you could use `auto`:

```
auto T= new pElement[numOfNodes]{};
```

Note that you're not only removing explicit casts
but also implicit casts.

You could also have used in C++

```
std::vector, which grows as needed
std::vector<ELEMENT*> T(numOfNodes, NULL);
```

Passing (numOfNodes, NULL) as arguments
allocates numOfNodes elements initialized 
with NULL.
Even while `std::vector` lives on the stack
the memory for the elements lives on the heap.
You would access it the usual way:

```
T[10]= new ELEMENT();
```

Even better, in modern C++:

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<ELEMENT> > T(numOfNodes);
```

will construct a vector of smart pointers
that will call delete whenever you set them
to other value

```
T[10].reset(new ELEMENT(1)); // will set the pointer to a new element initialized with 1
T[10].reset(new ELEMENT(2)); // will set the pointer to a another new element
```

initialized with 2 and delete properly the old ELEMENT initialized with 1

```
T[10]->doSomething();
```

will work as usual.